# Non-field parameters in class constructor?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to have constructor parameters that don't become fields? For example,

```scala
class Foo(p1: String, p2: Int) {
    val f1 = p1 * p2
}
```

The only field I want is `f1`, not `p1` and `p2`. The idea is to derive fields from parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is good as it is - both `p1` and `p2` aren't fields here, just `f1`. Making them fields is opt-in rather than opt-out (except for case classes, where all parameters are also fields, and you can't do anything about it).

To *make* them fields, you'd have to add `var` or `val`, something like

```
class Foo(val p1: String, var p2: Int)
```

EDIT:
In case you want a field with the same name as a parameter but a different type or something, you can do something like this:

```
class Foo(p1: String, val p2: Int) {
  //Can be val if you want
  var _p1: Int = (p1 : String).toInt
  def p1: Int = _p1
  def p1_=(p1: Int) = _p1 = p1 //An optional setter
}
```

This is practically the same as having a field called `p1`.

If you also want to set fields using some complex operations and use local variables, you can use blocks (and maybe an auxiliary constructor)

```
class Foo(p1: String, val p2: Int) {
  val _p1: Int = {
    val intermediateVariable: String = p1
    intermediateVariable.toInt
  }
  def p1: Int = _p1
```

or

```
class Foo(val p1: Int) {

  def this(p1: String) = this({
    val uselessIntermediateVariable = p1.toInt
    uselessIntermediateVariable
  })
}
```

Comment: Haha, you are right. I misremembered. I thought they default to `val`. A related question: is it possible to have both a non-field parameter and a filed with the same name?

Comment: What is `p1_` for?

Comment: Cool. One step further, possible to have temp variables that don't become field used in the process of deriving fields from parameters?

Comment: It doesn't work in my case but I discovered `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

In a simple class, if you don't add any modifier as val or var, the parameters of the constructor are private elements. [Example:](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/2r8IiRk/3)

```
class C(val a: Int, b: Int) {
  val c = a + b
}

val i = new C(1,2)

println(i.a) // it's public 
println(i.b) // this line won't allow you to compile, it's private
println(i.c) // also public
```

The exception is made is you make a case class, with case modifier all the parameters of the constructor will be public. You can make them private marking as private the parameter. [Example:](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/Xx9ud56/4)

```
case class C(a: Int, private val b: Int) {
  val c = a + b
}

val i = new C(1,2)

println(i.a) // it's public 
println(i.b) // this line won't allow you to compile, it's private
println(i.c) // also public
```

Comment: Now I see why I misremembered. I confused case class constructor with class constructor.

Comment: In the first case `b` isn't private, it isn't stored at all.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the existing answers, non-case class parameters *can* automatically become fields, but only if they are used in methods or `lazy val` initializers, e.g.

```
class Foo(p1: String, p2: Int) {
    val f1 = p1 * p2
    def m1() = p1 + p1
}
```

will make `p1` a field. There's no way to avoid it other than not using them in such a way.